# Proper bullet symbol in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook, bullets

I am writing a document in French and I am missing the long dash symbol which is the one to use for lists. Unfortunately I only have these ridiculous symbols that nobody wants to use:

[image]

How can I get the long dash symbol as default for lists?

Comment: What happens if you click on "Define New Bullet..."? ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill, well I have a dialog where I can select a Symbol, but no way to find `U+2013` in this list or enter it. Then I cannot find a way to use this new symbol as default.

Comment: I'm afraid there is no way to set a default Bullet. For your reference: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1de054e8-f841-4eb7-97aa-a2bf3bbefef4/windows-outlook-question?forum=outlook

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add it to your Bullet library, click on Define New Bullet... then Symbol button. In the dialog that appears, you just need to change the font (at top) from "Symbol" to "(normal text)" at top of dropdown list.  Then you can search for your character code 2013 to find and select your en dash as the bullet symbol.
[image]